# "Expected parameter name followed by ':'" 's error happen many times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

"Expected parameter name followed by ':'" 's error happen many times.
I wanna delete cache from my UIWebView system.
I wrote ViewController like

```
import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate  {

        @IBOutlet weak var webBrowser: UIWebView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let url = NSURL(string:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/")
            let request = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
            self.webBrowser.delegate = self
            self.webBrowser.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
            URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
            URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
            URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
        }

        func webView(_webBrowser,;: UIWebView,
                     shouldStartLoadWith, request: URLRequest,
                     navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    }
```

But in this part

```
func webView(_webBrowser,;: UIWebView,
             shouldStartLoadWith, request: URLRequest,
             navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

many errors happen like
[image: many errors]

Xcode suggested me how to fix these error, for example "Fix it insert "_:" ",but if I ordered these the way to fix these errors, other errors happened.So,I cannot fix them.
How can I fix them?I think I made a mistake in a point of syntax, but I do not know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two mistakes in your code:

1. You didn't put the `{` and `}` for the method and the method expected to return a `bool`
2. And most important issue is the function signature you've written is entirely wrong

So the correct way to use that function is like:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cause of syntax error.update your delegate method to like below

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```